# BayesA, BayesB, etc

Tags: prediction, bioinformatics

I would like to get a plain English explanation of BayesA, BayesB.  I found that a lot in bioinformatic literature but found nothing in Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: Are you referring to these definitions for BayesA and BayesB, from Meuwissen, Hayes, and Goddard (2001):  http://www.genetics.org/content/157/4/1819.long

Comment: Yes that's the context.  I just got lost in those math notations/semantic.  If there's a "hello world" example, it would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, BayesA is a mixed model that assumes that each marker is a random effect, whereas snpBLUP assumes that all markers make a single random effect. They call it BayesA because it is solved via MCMC because REML takes too long.
Then, BayesB is the same thing but it has a variable selection - which means that the model can assign zero effect to a markers. Since it runs through MCMC, it will never be a true zero but something very close to it.

You can check this to get the ABC of how these models are solved http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00122-016-2750-y